Como agregar total por fila en pivot
Estoy haciendo una consulta en sql server, usando pivot, mi pregunta es como puedo agregar un total por fila.
Esta es mi consulta:
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT l.Id_Linea
   ,l.Descripcion AS Modelo
   ,c.Descripcion AS Color
   ,a.punto
   ,SUM(a.pares) AS Pares
FROM Linea As l
INNER JOIN Producto AS p ON p.Id_Linea = l.Id_Linea
INNER JOIN Color AS c ON c.Id_Color = p.Id_Color
INNER JOIN  Programa AS pr ON pr.Id_Producto = p.Id_Producto
INNER JOIN Avances AS a ON a.id_programa = pr.id_programa
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, a.inyeccion) BETWEEN  '18/03/2024' AND  '23/03/2024' AND a.turno =  '1'
GROUP BY l.Id_Linea, l.Descripcion, c.Descripcion, a.punto
) AS RPT
PIVOT
(
SUM(pares)
FOR [punto] IN ([15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], 
[27], [28], [29], [30], [31], [32], [33])
)AS PT

Este es el resultado que me muestra:


Si no quieres cambiar mucho tu consulta, la solución es sumar todas las columnas.
SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT l.Id_Linea
   ,l.Descripcion AS Modelo
   ,c.Descripcion AS Color
   ,a.punto
   ,SUM(a.pares) AS Pares
   ,[15] + [16] + [17] + [18] + [19] + [20] + [21] + [22] + [23] + [24] + [25] + [26] + 
    [27] + [28] + [29] + [30] + [31] + [32] + [33] AS Total
FROM Linea As l
INNER JOIN Producto AS p ON p.Id_Linea = l.Id_Linea
INNER JOIN Color AS c ON c.Id_Color = p.Id_Color
INNER JOIN  Programa AS pr ON pr.Id_Producto = p.Id_Producto
INNER JOIN Avances AS a ON a.id_programa = pr.id_programa
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, a.inyeccion) BETWEEN  '18/03/2024' AND  '23/03/2024' AND a.turno =  '1'
GROUP BY l.Id_Linea, l.Descripcion, c.Descripcion, a.punto
) AS RPT
PIVOT
(
SUM(pares)
FOR [punto] IN ([15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], 
[27], [28], [29], [30], [31], [32], [33])
)AS PT;

En lo personal, en vez de escribir PIVOT, prefiero usar el agregado condicional para convertir las filas en columnas. Así, el total se calcula solo dejando el agregado sin condiciones.
SELECT  l.Id_Linea
   ,l.Descripcion AS Modelo
   ,c.Descripcion AS Color
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 15 THEN a.pares END) AS [15]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 16 THEN a.pares END) AS [16]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 17 THEN a.pares END) AS [17]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 18 THEN a.pares END) AS [18]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 19 THEN a.pares END) AS [19]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 20 THEN a.pares END) AS [20]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 21 THEN a.pares END) AS [21]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 22 THEN a.pares END) AS [22]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 23 THEN a.pares END) AS [23]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 24 THEN a.pares END) AS [24]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 25 THEN a.pares END) AS [25]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 26 THEN a.pares END) AS [26]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 27 THEN a.pares END) AS [27]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 28 THEN a.pares END) AS [28]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 29 THEN a.pares END) AS [29]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 30 THEN a.pares END) AS [30]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 31 THEN a.pares END) AS [31]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 32 THEN a.pares END) AS [32]
   ,SUM( CASE WHEN a.punto = 33 THEN a.pares END) AS [33]
   ,SUM( a.pares)
FROM       Linea    AS l
INNER JOIN Producto AS p  ON p.Id_Linea     = l.Id_Linea
INNER JOIN Color    AS c  ON c.Id_Color     = p.Id_Color
INNER JOIN Programa AS pr ON pr.Id_Producto = p.Id_Producto
INNER JOIN Avances  AS a  ON a.id_programa  = pr.id_programa
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, a.inyeccion) BETWEEN  '18/03/2024' AND  '23/03/2024' 
AND   a.turno =  '1'
GROUP BY l.Id_Linea,
         l.Descripcion, 
         c.Descripcion;

